# Put bcp inside a transaction with another tsql statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, bcp

After a bcp output command from tsql did its work (export a file) you generally want to cleanup the source afterwards.
This typically involves truncating the source table or setting a flag that the records are indeed processed.

If you don't clean up the next export will of course included the old and already exported rows.

My experiments show that you cannot place a bcp inside a transaction. Its my assumption that it is an out of process tool and doesn't join the initiating transaction (correct me if I'm wrong please).

The question is if its possible to have these 2 actions be performed as a **unit of work** in some other way? Either it fails together are they succeed together.

I was hoping there was a "post action" that you could pass to bcp so that bcp itself could guarantee transaction like begaviour.

Thanks for the ideas, Tom

Answer (score 0):

How about this: flag all rows by writing their PK ids into a processing table.  Next run the BCP out using xp_cmdshell and check for errors ([see this article for an example](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Error+Handling/69196/)). If everything ran great then use the processing table to find the original rows to delete.  Otherwise, clear out that processing table and you're ready to try again.